# Почему ошибка в выводе? Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql, база-данных, mysqli, preparedstatement

Почему вылазит **Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in...**?

```
$idGoods = $_POST['add_id'];
$idCookie = $_POST['id_cookie'];

function getGoodsCartModal($p1) {
    global $mysqli;
    $sql = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE idGoods = '$p1'");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 's', $p1);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($sql);
    $a = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    return $a;
    mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
}
$getGoodsCartModal = getGoodsCartModal($idGoods);

if(isset($_POST['add_id'])){
    echo $getGoodsCartModal['idCookie'];
}
```

Ругается на строку 18, где **mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql, 's', $p1);**

Comment: warning в переводе с английского — предупреждение. ошибка в переводе на английский — error

Comment: Отличный ответ, а главное очень мне помог!

Comment: Надо обратить внимание на это место: `idGoods = '$p1'"`

Comment: Такая же функция норм работает в другом скрипте. Тут же idGoods в таблице есть, значение в $p1 тоже есть. Что ж не так то?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$sql = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 'SELECT * FROM cart WHERE idGoods = ?');
```

Раз вы используете prepared statements (mysqli_stmt_bind_param), не нужно добавлять в запрос инъекцию.

---

```
return $a;
mysqli_stmt_close($sql); // Недостижимый код, строку нужно либо удалить, либо перести выше return
```

Comment: Допиши еще стандартный комментарий, который вы вешаете к code-only ответам.

Comment: ААААААА.....подготовленный же запрос блин..... Это значит что надо отдыхать почаще во время кодинга)

Comment: Это почему-то довольно распространённая ошибка. За эту неделю было не менее трёх подобных вопросов. В прошлые разы ограничивался комментариями, в этот раз решил таки разместить ответ.

Comment: @vp_arth, вам отдельная благодарность за ответ. Изменения внёс, полёт нормальный. Думаю что в дальнейшем ещё много вопросов будет мной задано в поиске решений более сложных задач.

Answer (score 1):

Продолжим урок английского, начатый коллегой aleksandr barakin

- number значит номер, количество
- variable означает переменная
- doesn't match означает не совпадает
- number означает номер, количество
- parameter означает параметр, знак подстановки
- prepared statement означает подготовленный запрос

то есть текст ошибки, в переводе с английского, означает, что количество переменных, которые мы привязаваем к запросу в функции bind_param, не соответствует количеству параметров (знаков вопроса) в запросе.

Идем в код и считаем:
количество переменных в bind_param: 1 (одна) штука
количество параметров: 0 (ноль) штук

Для решения проблемы необходимо привести количество параметров (знаков вопроса) в запросе соответствие с количеством переменных функции bind_param. т.е. добавить в запрос параметр (знак вопроса) в количестве 1 (одна) штука. Удалив при этом из запроса переменную. Поскольку суть подготовленных запросов и состоит в том, чтобы заменять переменные на параметры.

В целом, проблема показывает преимущество грамотности (т.е. умения читать) и знания иностранных языков перед неграмотностью (т.е. неумением читать) и незнанием иностранных языков в объеме слов number, variable и parameter.

Comment: нет, я так не думаю. но легкая ирония, и акцент на том что сообщения об ошибках надо читать, совсем не помешает.

Comment: @Ипатьев, я знаю перевод данного сообщения, но без определённого знания PHP допускаю как видите пропуски в возможно для кого-то банальных моментах. Но ученье свет и такие гуру (судя по репутации на форуме) наводят на светлые мысли.

Comment: @Кариот я не понимаю этого. что значит "я знаю перевод данного сообщения"? Ну то есть если ты проехал на красный и въехал в другую машину, то достаточно сказать "я знаю, что на красный ехать нельзя!" и всё ОК? Надо наверное не просто "знать", а какие-то выводы делать, практические? То есть не просто "знать", а не ехать на красный. Не просто "знать перевод", а применить на практике, посмотреть что не так с количеством параметров?

Comment: @vp_arth я как раз считаю, что ответы, которые дают готовое решение и не объясняют, как прийти к нему самостоятельно, приносят больше вреда чем пользы. Да, я согласен, что тон моего ответа мог бы быть и лучше. Но по сути, всегда важнее объяснить общий принцип, а не сунуть готовое. А если уж и подходить к вопросу так, то его следует закрыть, поскольку вопросы, вызванные банальной невнимательностью, не подходят сайту по тематике.

Comment: Форум для того и нужен, чтобы помогать ответами на различные вопросы новичков , а так же поддерживать диалоги с бывалыми. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Кариот форум - возможно. Но Stack Overflow - не форум. И диалоги здесь не очень приветствуются. Как и  вопросы, на которые уже есть ответ

Comment: Что же тогда Stack Overflow, если не форум?

Comment: @Кариот форум - это место для разговоров. Stack overflow - это сервис вопросов и ответов. Если новичок не умеет пользоватья поиском, если вопрос вызван невнимательностью, если просто хочется поговорить, то такие вопросы не относятся к тематике Stack Overflow.